# getOrientation to detect turning around x-axis; getRotationMatrix returning all zeros

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I'm using getOrientation (R, I, gravity, magVals) to detect turning around the x-axis. For now I am just trying to display the x-value reading on the screen, but the value is always zero, and I don't know why.

EDIT: After some more investigation I found that getRotationMatrix is always returning all zeros. The accelerometer and magnetic field params are fine though. I still don't know why though.

EDIT: I added ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions, the result is still the same. **Note that I have also gone through every past question that I could find that deals with getRotationMatrix problems, but nothing has fixed my problem.**

My implementation method: 
1. Add accelerometer and magnetic field listeners 
2. Call getRotationMatrix every time an accelerometer/magnetic field event occurs 
3. Pass the rotation matrix into a getOrientation call (also called whenever an event occurs)

Here is the part of onCreateView in my fragment dealing with the orientation:

```
        TextView xRotation = new TextView(rootView.getContext());

        //Magnetic Sensor
        Sensor magneticSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        SensorEventListener magneticSel = new OtherSensorEventListener (xRotation);
        sensorManager.registerListener(magneticSel, magneticSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        //Accelerometer
        Sensor accelSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        SensorEventListener accelSel = new OtherSensorEventListener(xRotation);
        sensorManager.registerListener(accelSel, accelSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        layout.addView(xRotation);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        return rootView;
```

Here is the OtherSensorEventListener() class:

```
    public static class OtherSensorEventListener implements SensorEventListener {

    float [] magVals = new float[3];
    float [] accelVals = new float [3];
    float [] RMatrix;
    TextView output;

    public OtherSensorEventListener(TextView output) {
        this.output = output;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {            
        switch(event.sensor.getType()) {

        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            magVals = event.values.clone();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            accelVals = event.values.clone();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (accelVals != null && magVals != null) {

            RMatrix = new float[16];

            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(RMatrix, null, accelVals, magVals);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(RMatrix, orientation);
            output.setText("X Rotation: " + orientation[1]);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}
}
```

These is the orientation global variable (declared inside of MainActivity):

```
    static float [] orientation = new float[3];
```

I am new to Android. I don't know if there are better ways to do this than getOrientation, but I have to use it as a part of my lab. Note: I'm not asking for you to do my lab for me, I just need help with debugging

Answer (score 0):

You passed in two difference listeners

```
new OtherSensorEventListener (xRotation);
```

Thus either of of the parameter `accelVals` or `magVals` is always a zero array, so `getOrientation` always returns `0`

Try

```
SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new OtherSensorEventListener (xRotation);
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, magneticSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, accelSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```